# C++ Boost property tree - Update tree by file

Tags: c++, boost, boost-propertytree

I'm using `Boost Property Tree` to load ini configuration files.
Using this library, I'm able to load each configuration file into one `boost::property_tree::ptree` object. Now I want to load multiple configuration files in one `ptree` object.
How can I do this job? Or how can I merge `ptree`s into one object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean to treat all the individual ini files as one big ini file? If so, you may just read each individual file into a string and then append all the strings together. Finally, load that string into `boost::property_tree::ptree`.